# In cscope how to search for a string with period in it?

Tags: ctags, cscope

In cscope how to search for a string with period in it? for eg. I have a line

```
.mount = testmount
```

in my code, but if i try to search for the C symbol or even text string .mount, i get every line that contains the word mount instead. Using backslash as an escape character doesn't seem to be working either.

Answer (score 1):

Search for egrep pattern instead of text or symbol if the search string has a period because a period is a valid input for searching egrep patterns and files but not for searching symbols or text.

When cscope is started, it will bring up the following options. Choose "Find this egrep pattern:".

```
Find this C symbol:
Find this global definition:
Find functions called by this function:
Find functions calling this function:
Find this text string:
Change this text string:
Find this egrep pattern:.mount
Find this file:
Find files:
```